# Remove row from second gridview when checkbox in first gridview is deselected using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Please i have 2 gridviews.
I have been able to pass row from the first gridview to the second gridview when checkbox in first gridview is selected.
But now I want to remove the row that was added to the second gridview when checkbox in the first gridview is deselected.
Here's my code

```
$(function () {
                // Calls when checkbox is checked.
                $('[id*=GridView1] [id*=GridView1_chkRow]').on('click', function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        //Second Gridview.
                        var gridview2 = $('[id*=gvSelected]');

                        //Get Row Which Checbox is Selected.
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                        //Ignoring the checkbox column so that it wont get added in second gridview.
                        var tds = $(tr).find('td').not('.IgnoreCheckBoxColumn');
                        var row = '<tr>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
                            row += tds[i].outerHTML;
                        }
                        row += '</tr>';

                        //Appending selected row to second gridview.
                        gridview2.append(row);
                    }
```

Comment: Manipulating aspnet Controls with javascript like that is not a good idea since all changes will be lost on PostBack.

Comment: What do you suggest I do and I have set the autopostback property to false so n changes is lost?

Comment: When that row is removed and the page is reloaded the row is back again since aspnet does not know it was removed using javascript. If you however are not using the data or doing a PostBack on that page then it can work.